# What functional programming terminology distinguishes between avoding modifying variables and objects?

Tags: functional-programming, terminology

In functional programming, what terminology is used to distinguish between avoiding modifying what a variable refers to, and avoiding modifying an object itself?

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443068/what-is-best-practice-in-ruby-to-avoid-misusing-assignment/5443320#5443320), in Ruby,

```
name += title
```

avoids modifying the object previously referred to by `name`, instead creating a new object, but regrettably makes `name` refer to the new object, whereas

```
full_title = name + title
```

not only avoids modifying objects, it avoids modifying what `name` refers to.

What terminology would you use for code that avoids the former?

Comment: Modifying a variable doesn't exist in a purely functional language, so I doubt you will get a useful answer here, aside from just 'functional programming'. I understand that the underlying object for `name` changes, but if we consider that its probably implemented as a pointer, then theres a change in pointer, which is a change in state.

Comment: In pure functional programming, you can't even do the former. In impure FP, assignment and definition/binding are often syntactically different.

Answer (score 1):

Using a name to refer to something other than what it did in an enclosing/previous scope is known as "shadowing" that name. It is indeed distinct from mutation. In Haskell, for example I can write

```
return 1 >>= \x -> return (x + 1) >>= \x -> print x.
```

The `x` that is printed is the one introduced by the second lambda, i.e., `2`.

In do notation this looks a bit more familiar:

```
foo = do
  x <- return 1
  x <- return (x + 1)
  print x
```

As I understand it, Erlang forbids aliasing altogether.

However, I suspect that mathepic is right in terms of Ruby -- its not just shadowing the name but mutating some underlying obect. On the other hand, I don't know Ruby that well...

Answer (score 1):

I think functional programming languages simply do not have any operators that *destructively* updates one of the source operands (is destructive update, perhaps, the term you're looking for?). A similar philosophy is seen in instruction set design: the RISC philosophy (increasingly used in [even the x86 architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#New_features), in the newer extensions) is to have three-operand instructions for binary operators, where you have to explicitly specify that the target operand is the same as one of the sources if you want destructive update.

For the latter, some hybrid languages (like [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/); the same terminologies are used in [X10](http://x10.codehaus.org/)) distinguish between *values* (`val`) and *variables* (`var`). The former cannot be reassigned, the latter can. If they point to a mutable object, then of course that object itself can still be modified.